# Do I need additivity of exact functor to commute with homology

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology, homological-algebra

This is a problem of Rotman, Homological Algebra 6.8.

Let $R,A$ be rings and $T:Mod_R\to Mod_A$ be exact additive functor. Show that $T$ commutes with homology(i.e. $H_n(TC,Td)\cong TH_n(C,d)$ where $C$ is a complex of $Mod_A$ and $d$ is the differential map).

It is obvious that by $T$ exactness, $Ker$ and $Coker$ are preserved. So $H_n(-)$ surely commutes with $T$ as $H_n(C)$ is a quotient of kernel and image$(=Ker(Coker(d_n))$. However I have never used additive property of $T$ at all. Did I produce a fake proof?

1. Why do I even need additiveness here?
2. However, it is clear that colimit is exact. Assume I am in some abelian category admits non finite limits and colimits. So colimit commutes with $H_n$. But $Hom(-,X)$ and colimit does not commute. So colimit is not additive?

---

I think the following are my answers to the questions.

1. Additiveness here is used to say $T(0)=0$.
2. $lim M_i\oplus lim N_i=lim(M_i\oplus N_i)$. There is natural embedding of $limM_i\to lim(M_i\oplus N_i)$. One can show surjectivity and injectivity. $lim$ should be additive as well.

In abelian category, functor is additive if only if it preserver finite direct sums.

Comment: An exact functor preserve finite limits and colimits, in particular direct sums. Thus an exact functor is always additive.